# Print a Jira issue with embedded images?

Tags: printing, jira

I'm trying to print a Jira issue from Jira 6.4.12.   I'd like to print it with the embedded screenshots, since these are important to understanding the issue.   But Jira doesn't seem to have any "Print As" function that allows printing the text and the images.   I can print the text but the images always appear as thumbnails or, even worse, placeholder images.

Is there an export (or whatever) for Jira that allows printing of the issue and the attached images full-sized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible with just the regular export of Jira. You can chose the format, but for attachments it will only print the attachment name.

To achieve this kind of functionality, you'll have to create a script that can connect to the Jira API and extract the data and attachments through that way so you can reassemble them the way you want them displayed, but this is not simple task.

You can also suggest this as a new feature directly on the Atlassian website : https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa so that they consider adding this to future versions.